# Delay between executions - PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to set a delay between 2 portion of code in PHP? I want something like this-

```
<?php
function firstFunc(){
    echo "anything";
}

function secondFunc(){
    echo "something";
}

// call first fumction
firstFunc();
// I want the script to wait for 2 seconds here, then call second function
secondFunc();
```

Is it possible?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delay the execution of something, you can use the `sleep($seconds)` function. Here's what the documentation says

> Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds.

It returns **zero** on success and **false** on error.

So you can do something like:

```
<?php
function firstFunc(){
    echo "anything";
}

function secondFunc(){
    echo "something";
}

// call first function
firstFunc();
sleep(2); //Delays execution for 2 seconds.
secondFunc();
?>
```

**Keep in mind though**, PHP is a server side language. The only thing the client will receive from a PHP script(if the client has to receive anything at all) is HTML(or CSS, JS and so on). So when you run this code, the page will show nothing for 2 seconds and then output `anything` and `something` together because the delay is happening at a server level, and not on client machine. If you want a kind a delay where `something` is visible on the screen and then after 2 seconds `anything` appears, you want to use JavaScript.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use function [sleep(int seconds)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)